# i have condition to add disabled class to my div after select multiple check boxes which is 5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

i have condition to add disabled class to my div after select multiple check boxes which is 5 . this code add disabled to all checkboxes div which includes the current selected as well.. so i want that it disabled only the unselected after 5 select boxes not on all div..

```html
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
<input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
<input type="checkbox" id="wapf_field_5fd25d21855fd_kd4ik" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
<img src="http://sweetshop.nantwichwebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/1.png">
<span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo Strawberry</span></span>
</div>
```

```
$(":checkbox[class='.wapf-input']").change(function(){
  if ($(":checkbox[class='.wapf-input']:checked").length == 2)                                              
   $('.wapf-swatch').addClass('disabled');  
  else                                                     
   $('.wapf-swatch').removeClass('disabled', false); 
});
```

Comment: Please make an [mcve] of the issue

Comment: What's your disable for?

Comment: Please add the HTML so we can reproduce this

Comment: @Adhitya its very simple check boxes click .. but i put a limit after 2 checkboxes no more selection until other uncheked.. but i need to disable the main div.. so it doesnot uncheck it again thats the issue

Comment: Are you using HTML for that? if yes, please added it.

Comment: check the html i have almost 20 same div with checkboxes i want to select random 5 and disable others but now when it reaches to 5 it disable all please help

Comment: here is link you can select 5 but it lso disable all http://sweetshop.nantwichwebdesign.co.uk/product/custom-sweet-bag/

Comment: @Taplar check the html i have almost 20 same div with checkboxes i want to select random 5 and disable others but now when it reaches to 5 it disable all please help

Comment: @mpora check the html i have almost 20 same div with checkboxes i want to select random 5 and disable others but now when it reaches to 5 it disable all please help

Comment: Hi , you need to disable the div ? or checkbox itself ?

Comment: @swati to add disabled class to the DIV  like this https://thesweetshophq.com/product/customise-your-own-sweet-bags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not(:checked)` to get all checkboxes which are not checked and then simply use `addClass` to add `disabled` class else use `removeClass` to remove the class

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".wapf-input").change(function() {
  //get checked checkbox length
  if ($(".wapf-swatch input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 2) {
    //get checkbox not checked add class disable
    $('.wapf-swatch > input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').closest(".wapf-swatch").addClass("disabled")
  } else {
    //remove class disabled
    $('.wapf-swatch').removeClass("disabled")

  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Strawberry</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span> Strawberr1</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo11</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo111</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo12</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: AWESOMEEEEE!! You save My day Swati... genius.. it taks me 2 days to do that but you are wesome hatsoff